# Как построить график тангенса tg(x) в WinForms Chart C#?

Tags: c#, диаграммы, график

Пытаюсь построить график тангенса в объекте Chart , но так как функция разрывная, то строит график неверно.
Как сделать, чтобы получилась нормальная тангенсоида?
На данный момент имею : (кейс 4)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1 && textBox1.Text.Length != 0 && textBox2.Text.Length != 0 && textBox3.Text.Length != 0 &&
        textBox4.Text.Length != 0 && textBox5.Text.Length != 0)
        {
            chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
            double a, b, c, start, end,step=1;
            const double incr = 0.1;
            start = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            end = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            a = double.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            b = double.Parse(textBox4.Text);
            c = double.Parse(textBox5.Text);
            step = (double)numericUpDown1.Value;

            chart1.Series[0].LegendText = comboBox1.Text;
            
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = start;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = end;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = step;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(0, end);


            switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0: for (double k = start; k <= end+incr; k += incr) chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(k, a * k + b); break;
                case 1: for (double k = start; k <= end + incr; k += incr) chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(k, a * k * k + b * k + c); break;
                case 2: for (double k = start; k <= end + incr; k += incr) chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(k, a * Sin(b * k) + c); break;
                case 3: for (double k = start; k <= end+incr; k += incr) chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(k, a * Cos(b * k) + c); break;
                case 4: for (double k = start; k <= end + incr; k += incr) chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(k, a * Tan(b*k) + c); break;

            }

            

        }
```

[image: График]

Comment: Полсказка: `double a, b, c, start, end, step` старайтесь объявлять переменные не заранее, а там, где вы начинаете их использовать. Так код будет проще читать. `double start = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);`

Comment: `Tan(b*k)` - покажите этот метод.